# CUDA - what's the most efficient way to compute euclidean distance between 2 float3?

Tags: cuda, distance, gpgpu

Currently I'm using the following code to compute the euclidean distance between two float3 which I took from one of the Nvidia samples.

```
inline __host__ __device__ float3 operator-(float3 a, float3 b) 
{
    return make_float3(a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y, a.z - b.z);
}


inline __host__ __device__ float dot(float3 a, float3 b)
{
 return a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y + a.z * b.z;
}


inline __host__ __device__ float euclideanDistance(float3 v)
{ 
return sqrtf(dot(v, v));
}
```

Is there any (maybe more low level) way to do it faster?

Comment: Do you really need the distance? Could you work in distance squared instead?

Comment: Building on what talonmies is implying.... `sqrtf` is going to dominate the compute time of the distance.

Comment: Note that CUDA has functions `norm3d{f}()` which is the best fit when computing the Euclidean distance of 3-vectors as they ensure maximum accuracy and avoid overflow in intermediate computation. If you need to normalize vectors, you would want to look at `rnorm3d{f}()` instead.

Comment: talonmies, that's a great suggestion! As I'm primarily using the distance just to compare it to a fixed radius there should be no problem if I compare the squared distance to the radius squared instead. I'll try that out.

Comment: njuffa, thanks for your suggestion. While talomnies suggestion is going to solve my immediate problem, some of my secondary kernels will require the exact distance. I'll test how much of a difference it makes.

Answer (score 2):

CUDA has functions `norm3d{f}()` in the math library which is the best fit when computing the Euclidean distance of 3-vectors as they ensure maximum accuracy and avoid overflow in intermediate computation. If you need to normalize vectors, you would want to look at `rnorm3d{f}()`. Those would be the canonical choice for this operation and should be optimal.

Note that it might be possible to run your computations in distance squared instead, rather than distance, which will eliminate the expensive square root operation and should be considerably faster than using the Euclidean distance.

[This answer mostly assembled from comments and added as a community wiki entry to get the question off the unanswered list for the CUDA tag]